# CSS fluid image replacement?

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image

Using CSS to replace text with an image is a well known practice.  CSS-Tricks has a museum of some techniques (http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageReplacement/).

But none of these allows for replacement with a fluid image (for example, a logo that stretches across 100% of a fluid page layout).  Is it possible to use CSS to do a fluid image replacement?

Almost all image replacement techniques use a background-image.  And I know that you can set `background-size: 100%`.  But it's not straightforward to get the height of the text element to scale with it's width because the browser doesn't consider the background image as part of the content.

I understand that any of the common image replacement techniques could be easily combined with media queries to incrementally change the size of the text element to specific height x width ratios that work.  But that is incremental, not fluid.

I did find a blog post that discusses this (http://viljamis.com/blog/2011/fluid-image-replacement.php).  But it turns out thay method actually requires putting an image in the html content.  I'm looking for real text replacement.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Took some fiddling, but I figured out a way.  The key is to use padding percentage to set the height, because `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` percentage is linked to container width (unlike `height`, which is linked to container height).

html

```
<h1 class="logo">The Logo</h1>
```

css

```
h1.logo {
    background-image: url('logo.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 29.8%;
    height: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Where `padding-top` is calculated by dividing the image height by width.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bXtRw/

I'll note that using `overflow: hidden` instead of `text-indent: -9999px` should also work.  But I get unstable behavior in Firefox.

Also, using `font-size: 0` instead of `height: 0` produces unstable behavior in Firefox.

Comment: for those who may be having confusing problems with this, be sure to ONLY set the `background-image` property, NOT the whole `background` shorthand, as setting a position will invalidate this awesome trick

Comment: @Warren, Is it possible to set the maximum size? say i don't want the logo to strect 100% of the width. Say after 200px, it will stay the same. Is it  possible?

Answer (score 0):

On the div that contains the background-image:

```
div {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px; //Adjust this number accordingly
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use a method identical to @Warren Whipple, but I usually use [compass](/questions/tagged/compass)/[sass](/questions/tagged/sass).  If you're not limited to using vanilla CSS, this method nicely abstracts a few pieces:

```
// Only works in Compass/Sass – not regular CSS!
h1.logo {

    $header-logo-image: "logo.png";

    background: image-url($header-logo-image) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: percentage( image-height($header-logo-image) / image-width($header-logo-image) );
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You should just have to replace the `$header-logo-image` variable with the name of your image.

---

In addition, I sometimes add: `max-width: image-width($header-logo-image);`, which will prevent the `h1` from being sized any larger than its background image.